# Azure CPU metric (Live Metrics Stream)

Tags: azure

Below shows the 'CPU Total' as displayed on the Azure Live Metrics page for our Web App which is scaled out to 4 x S3 instances.

It's not clear to me (despite much research) if this CPU Total is a percentage of the max CPU available for the instance or something else. I have noticed that the CPU Total has crept above 100% from time to time, which makes me question if it is a percentage of the total.

If this metric is not a % of the total: is there anywhere in the Azure portal that will show you the % CPU usage of your servers as a % and not of a % multiplied by core count or anything else?

[image]

Comment: Ever find the answer to this?  To add to the confusion, these CPU totals do not coincide at all with the CPU totals presented by the metrix in the App Service Plan that the servers belong to.

Comment: Nope. Still have no clue.

Comment: I'm assuming still not?